# C# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException Error for no reason

Tags: c#

For the past month I've been getting data with a C# program in tandem with a company's API. Just yesterday all the sudden it would no longer work, even though I haven't changed the code at all. Here's the code:

```
    public string GetMatchCode()
        {
            //this could be loaded from config file or other source
            string connectString = "Server=123.123.1.23;Database=blah_users;Uid=blah_data;Pwd=blahblah;";
            string sql = "SELECT MAX(match_id) FROM `data_blah`";
            using (var connect = new MySqlConnection(connectString))
            using (var command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connect))
            {
                connect.Open();
                return command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
        }
```

And I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Access denied for user 'blah_data'@'cpe-86-80-21-54.san.res.rr.com' (using password: YES)
```

Any idea what could have happened and how to fix it? The only thing I think could've happened is that my support ticket dealing with node.js compatibility was executed wrong by support employees. Thanks!

Comment: If you haven't changed anything, simply contact the company. The error says you've been denied access, but we can't help you with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your db user's permission has failed. The user may have been removed; the permissions may have been modified. Contact the db owner.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you are not authenticating: Either incorrect credentials or server needs a different method. Try disabling "sslmode" like below:

```
 public string GetMatchCode()
    {
        //this could be loaded from config file or other source
        string connectString = "Server=123.123.1.23;Database=blah_users;Uid=blah_data;Pwd=blahblah;sslmode=none;";
        string sql = "SELECT MAX(match_id) FROM `data_blah`";
        using (var connect = new MySqlConnection(connectString))
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connect))
        {
            connect.Open();
            return command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
    }
```

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
string sql = "SELECT MAX(match_id) FROM `data_blah`";
```

Isn't it supposed to be " ' " instead of " ` " surrounding "data_blah"?

Comment: No. Backticks are used for enclosing identifiers such as table and column names, quote for for enclosing string literals.